# Python Virtualenvwrapper's "workon" and Zsh

Tags: python, zsh, virtualenvwrapper

I created a virtualenv using `virtualenvwrapper` called `augpy`. When I type `workon augpy` it works fine and get's activated properly. However when I try to list the virtualenvs using `workon` alone, I get a strange output:

```
$ workon
]7;file://new-host.home/Users/Me/.virtualenvsaugpy
```

I don't know why that is - maybe it is confused about the shell I'm using? I am currently using zsh (5.0.2, OSX 10.8) plus `oh-my-zsh` as my default shell. When I type `workon` in *bash*, I get the correct result (and autocomplete also works):

```
$workon
augpy
```

Is there anything specific I should set for zsh?

Comment: What oh-my-zsh theme are you using? It looks like you're getting prompt sequences in your prompt (`]7;`). You could try disabling oh-my-zsh - otherwise, without further information (`zshrc` contents, for example) this question's probably difficult to answer.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I disabled oh-my-zsh and `workon` worked fine in zsh. About the version of OMZ, I'm not sure but it is from master branch as of yesterday. The theme is "steeef" and loaded plugins are `git python pip golang django history history-substring-search terminalapp brew`. Not sure how to fix the OMZ prompt though.

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer, I'm afraid.

The issue you see has nothing to do with oh-my-zsh.  The problem is introduced on line 539 of `virtualenvwrapper.sh`.

Subshells invoked in zsh return their last working directory on STDOUT, wrapped in control characters.  This is easy to verify:

```
(cd /) | cat -v
```

I cannot find this feature documented anywhere.  Perhaps it was introduced recently, say in zsh 5.0?

The `fmt` command invoked in the `virtualenvwrapper_show_workon_options()` function in `virtualenvwrapper.sh` makes this returned path visible, screwing up the output.

### Update:

Prompted by evadeflow's comment below, I did a little further digging and found that the actual issue lay with the way in which I was changing the OS X Terminal's proxy icon.  And indeed, it turns out that oh-my-zsh uses exactly the same method.  As of this writing, I have filed a pull request on GitHub to get this fixed in oh-my-zsh.

Comment: I haven't been able to confirm this behavior after downloading ```zsh-5.0.2``` and building from source. ```zsh-5.0.2% (cd /) | cat -v``` displays nothing. Are you sure oh-my-zsh isn't implicated in this?

Comment: No, I wouldn't go near a hairball like oh-my-zsh.

But this does mean that the problem is caused by some zsh configuration parameter;  I just have to go figure out which one!  Thanks!

Comment: I should have checked whether a "clean" zsh configuration causes the problem (It's easy to create one by changing into an empty directory and executing `ZDOTDIR=. zsh -l`).

I've traced the problem to a widely-publicised method of changing the proxy icon in the Mac OS X Terminal application to that of the current directory.  I first came across it here:

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110722211753852

I'm assuming this is included as part of oh-my-zsh.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be resolved by emitting the control-character protected path to STDERR rather than STDOUT.

In the previously-linked macworld hint, this would require changing the command `printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"` to `printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL" 1>&2`.